# Bootstrap label moving other spans

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a label to tell when something is InProcess but the label moves another span in the panel even though it has plenty of room to move around.

How it is right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVeTa.jpg

How it should be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsw3C.jpg

Here's the code for it.

```
                    <div class="panel-body log-work-lot-container">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li class="log-work-item-lot" data-ng-click="vm.SetActiveBatch(batch);" data-ng-class="{'selected' : batch.IsActive}" 
                                data-ng-repeat="batch in vm.Batches" data-ng-show="!batch.IsScrapped && !batch.IsCompleted">
                                <div style="text-align:center;">
                                    <span class="pull-left">0000{{batch.Name}}</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right label label-info" data-ng-show="batch.InProcess"> In Process </span>
                                    <span style="">QTY {{batch.Quantity}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I think the best you can do is create a row with 3 cols size 4 inside.

Comment: You can always hard code the width. Or you can do that ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.list-unstyled .pull-left { margin-right: -100%; }
.list-unstyled .pull-right { margin-left: -100%; }
```

Please note this is a hack-ish way of doing it and makes your left/right elements overlap the centered content if they don't fit on one row. In order not to overlap when on very small screens, I updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/vda2g0kq/1/) based on your markup. It's not perfect, but it's better than overlapping them :).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vda2g0kq/     That should be a good indicator. If you're missing anything tell me. Thats the easiest way to show it without needing to show entire page. Also what you tried didn't change anything

Comment: I misunderstood the request. You want the text in the middle to be center aligned regardless of the left and right elements. Is this correct?

Comment: Yea! The bottom one is correct except when you add in the label it becomes the top one. I need it to stay like the bottom one while adding the label.

Comment: See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/vda2g0kq/1/) for very small screens. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grid structure to organize data in column formats. 
An example - http://www.bootply.com/5FLFCdIny1

(Above example uses only col-xs-*, which will display data in column format for all kind of devices. You can customize display based on screen size)

Comment: Please note that the Bootstrap's grid system is just that: a grid system, not an alignment system. It's intended for page layouts, not for labels alignment. Using it for alignment over-complicates the markup and often leads to hard to debug margin/padding problems, especially when used inside small elements that are already contained in a `.col-*`. One should use proper alignment properties, such as `float`s (box model) or `flexbox` alignment.